# @OneToMany mapping for Collection in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

Whenever we have a bidirectional mapping of `@OneToMany` relation, then we use a Collection in the parent entity to collect all the child entities. However it is always recommended to have smaller number of child entities for performance concerns. It is said to have `@ManyToOne` unidirectional mapping in child and using a query if we need children associated with parent. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you read that.There is no general rule.

But consider:

1. If you think how it is mapped to tables, the child table will have a foreign key to the parent table. In the rdbms side, you will not have an explicit "collection" in the parent, it's implicit by the foreign key. So the ManyToOne tends to reflect the implementation.
2. If you map one to many, this means you have a collection in the parent. If it has many children, it might take a lot of memory.
3. In many situations you don't need the children when retrieving the parent. (This of course can also be solved using a lazy collection.)
4. If the parent has a collection, when retrieving the children you need to execute the query it is said you should executed to retrieve the children.

Maybe this helps you clarify somewhat the supposed recommendation.

Comment: This was not what i was searching for.